# Density of Unbounded Aliquot Sequences

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $s_1(n)=\big{(}\sum_{d|n}d\big{)}-n=\sigma_1(n)-n$ be the restricted divisor sum, and define $s_k(n)=s_1(s_{k-1}(n))$ as the $k^{th}$ term of the [aliquot sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AliquotSequence.html) starting at $n$. The Catalan Dickson Conjecture states that every sequence is bounded; in other words, every sequences either terminates at 1 or enters a cycle. Though this conjecture is not proven to date, I was wondering if any weaker forms of the conjecture have been proven. For example, has any statement been made regarding the density of integers which have non-terminating sequence (clearly a nonzero density would imply infinitude, but has it been shown that they might have zero density)?
Guy and Selfridge [argue](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0384669-X/S0025-5718-1975-0384669-X.pdf) that most even sequences should diverge, and most odd sequences should terminate, so would it be reasonable to conjecture that the density of non-terminating aliquot sequences approaches a half?

Comment: Well, having even one sequence be unbounded, would prove there are infinitely many.This is provable by the fact that, if the aliquot successor of a supposed unbounded sequence start is bounded, then so is the unbounded sequence start.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee yes, but what density would that infinite set have within the integers?

Comment: wouldn't that be related to the [abundancy index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number#Related_concepts) of consecutive terms ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I doubt it... The density would not necessarily depend on the abundancy index (as it varies through iterations of the sequence)